# to solve problem with geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

Credicard charges $18\%$ p.a. on the average amount owing each month. A minimum payment of $5\%$ of the amount owing, including interest, is required. Assume that each month is $1/12$ of a year. With $\$1000$ cash advance taken out on the first day will result the billing amount $\$1015$ at the end of the month.

(a) show that minimum payment of $\$50.75$ is required and the amount owing at the beginning of the second month is $\$964.25$

(b) If, each month, the minimum amount is paid, what is the total amount to be repaid by the Credicard holder?

(c) Credicard does not want "loan to infinity". What methods credit card companies could adopt in order to limit repayment to a finite time?

my solution:
(a) minimum payment = $1015 \times 0.05 = 50.75$
amount owing beginning of the second month $= 1015 - 50.75 = 964.25$

(b) Need help to solve question b

Comment: You have to escape dollar signs with a backslash.  They are used to set of $\LaTeX$ on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Each month, the balance is multiplied by $(1+0.015)(1-0.05)=0.96425$ as you demonstrated for the first month.  The payment is then multiplied by that amount, making the payment a geometric series.  You just need to sum it.

Comment: Great.....GP series with a = 50.75 and r = 0.96425........answer is $1419.58